# retrieving list of telegram messages via telethon is not being saved in mongo db

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, telegram, telethon

trying to save messages(retrieved through telethon) are not being saved... error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80ItH.png)

code is:

```
for chat in chats:
    # with TelegramClient('mysession', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        for message in client.iter_messages(chat, offset_date=datetime.date(2023, 1, 31), reverse=True):
            # print(message)
            my_list.append(message)
collection.insert_many(my_list)
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You need to ensure `message` if of the datatypes accepted for insert_many.

Comment: Please include the error message as text inside the question, so that others can read it more easily, even if the image service gets rid of the image.

Comment: @ray message is being stored in class list, how can i convert it to dict in order to save it to mongodb

Comment: by the way mongodb also stores data in class list as well. why can't it saving it here